# TFS not showing svg embedded in markdown files

Tags: visual-studio, svg, tfs, markdown

I have some markdown files (.md) in my project, which embed SVG images with the usual `![]()` format. When I preview the markdown files in Visual Studio Code, the embedded SVG images are shown correctly.

However, when I try to preview those markdown files in visualstudio.com (TFS-git repository), the images are not shown, although regular bitmaps do. If I right-click the failed images and choose to 'open in another tab or window', the SVGs are shown correctly.

Is there a way to make it work correctly in visualstudio.com?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

Using macOS/Safari, when I open the developer console, the URL returning 404 is mentioned as: 
[https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{repo}/_git/uml/actors.svg](https://%7Baccount%7D.visualstudio.com/%7Brepo%7D/_git/uml/actors.svg)

But, when I right click the missing image and select 'Open image in new tab' it opens:
[https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{guid1}/_api/_versioncontrol/itemContent?repositoryId={guid2}&path=%2Fdocs%2Fuml%2Factors.svg&version=GBmaster&contentOnly=true&__v=5](https://%7Baccount%7D.visualstudio.com/%7Bguid1%7D/_api/_versioncontrol/itemContent?repositoryId=%7Bguid2%7D&path=%2Fdocs%2Fuml%2Factors.svg&version=GBmaster&contentOnly=true&__v=5)

The last link shows the image correctly

Comment: What `Content-Type` is the server serving the SVGs with?

Comment: Well, indeed it is returning 404. But, as mentioned, when I grab the URL and paste it in a browser's URL field, it is shown

Comment: Are you able to open the link https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{repo}/_git/uml/actors.sv‌​g in Safari? Do you use the latest macOS/Safari? How about using a relative path?

Comment: Do you mean the svg image cannot display from TFS/VSTS web portal? I just tried a markdown file with svg image embedded, it can be displayed correctly.

Comment: Hi @Eddie-MSFT, yes, it is not displayed in the web portal. I am using `![title](subfolder/file.svg)`  and `![title](./subfolder/file.svg)`

Answer (score 2):

TFS Web portal does not support display the svg image in markdown if the svg image is hosted in TFS repository(TFVC&Git), I have help you submit a feature request on VSTS User Voice, you can vote it here: [Support displaying the svg image in markdown from webportal](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16060783-support-displaying-the-svg-image-in-markdown-from).

As a workaround for now, you can place the svg file in a public network path and then use the address in the markdown. For example:

```
![Alt text](https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kiwi.svg)
```

Comment: That's quiet disappointing. Per my experience, a uservoice request will take forever. Publishing in an external network generates a lot of overhead. Better I publish directly on github.

Comment: @Jaime Publish the svg image to github and then use it in the markdown from TFS would also works.

Comment: Why I would do that? Either I would use github or TFS. Maintaining both sounds simply insane.